# Abstract Factory - getting LKN2019 of death error message

Tags: c++, linker, factory

I know I must be missing on one of those details that you can't just seem to spot, then after one month it hits you "Evrika !".

Basically, what I have to do is implement an abstract factory class for shapes, but I keep getting the LKN2019 error message related to the .obj created from my shape factory code.

It looks a little like this:

shapefactory.h

```
#ifndef SHAPEFACTORY_H__
#define SHAPEFACTORY_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "shape.h"
#include "circle.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "triangle.h"

using namespace std;

typedef Shape *(createShapeFunction)(void);




class ShapeFactory
{
public:
    static void registerFunction(const string &, const createShapeFunction *);
    static Shape *createShape(const string &);
    static Shape *createShape(istream &);
private:
    static map <string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions;
    ShapeFactory();
    static ShapeFactory *getShapeFactory();
};




#endif
```

shapefactory.cpp

```
    #include "shapefactory.h"





void ShapeFactory::registerFunction(const string & ID, const crateShapeFunction * CR )
{
    creationFunctions[ID] = CR;
}




Shape* ShapeFactory::createShape(const string & shapeName)
{
    map <string, crateShapeFunction *>::iterator it = creationFunctions.find(shapeName);
    if( it != creationFunctions.end() )
        return it->second();
    return NULL;

}


Shape* ShapeFactory::createShape(istream & in)
{
    string shapeName;
    cout << "Desired figure: ";
    in >> shapeName;

    map <string, crateShapeFunction *>::iterator it = creationFunctions.find(shapeName);
    if( it != creationFunctions.end() )
        return it->second();

    return NULL;

}



ShapeFactory::ShapeFactory()
{

    registerFunction("circle", &Circle::Create);
    registerFunction("rectangle", &Rectangle::Create);
    registerFunction("triangle", &Triangle::Create);

}



ShapeFactory* ShapeFactory::getShapeFactory()
{
    static ShapeFactory instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

I probably screwed up somewhere in the implementation of the methods, but I simply cannot see where. Any sort of timely help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
The error looked like this

Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::map,class std::allocator >,class Shape * (__cdecl*)(void),struct std::less,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > const ,class Shape * (__cdecl*)(void)> > > ShapeFactory::creationFunctions" (?creationFunctions@ShapeFactory@@0V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@P6APAVShape@@XZU?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@P6APAVShape@@XZ@std@@@2@@std@@A)   C:\Proj1\shapefactory.obj

before defining the map in my header as alexrider suggested. Thank you - it works now.

Comment: Please include the **complete** error message.  "LKN2019" is only a part of the message you got.

Comment: Doing `using namespace std;` in header files might badly surprise some time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing definition of `static map <string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions;`
This can be fixed by adding

```
map <string, createShapeFunction *> ShapeFactory::creationFunctions;
```

Into shapefactory.cpp
BTW pasting actual error message you get would be helpful.